# JSlider limit thumb movement

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

Is it possible to limit the movement of the JSlider thumb? It should not be possible for the user to move the slider thumb past a lower and upper limit value.

Edit:

I set the minimum and maximum values for the slider (e.g. from 1..100). But I have another control which limits the range of values for the slider, let's say from 30..60. Now the user should not be able to move the slider thumb below 30 and above 60, but the minimum and maximum values should still be 1 and 100.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows you settings for the slider's `BoundedRangeModel`.

Comment: This is exactly the way a JSlider works. You specify the min/max when you create the slider. Read the JSlider API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Sliders` for more information.

Comment: `But I have another control which limits the range of values for the slider, let's say from 30..60.` - then reset the min/max value to match the other control. It doesn't make sense to have two different values. The user will think the slider is broken because it doesn't slide to the displayed min/max.

Comment: Moreover, it will limit the useful resolution of the slider at a given size.

Comment: The first slider shows the current position in a video playback. The range limits the frames which are currently displayed. The user can change the range during playback.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have another control that sets the ranges for the slider, you may want to look into a RangeSlider that can supply the upper and lower bounds on a single slider (it has 2 thumbs)

Here are some different approaches from the web:

- [Creating a Java Swing range slider](http://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/)
- [MultiThumbSlider](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ThumbSliderExample2.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I am using the range slider in the first example to limit the range of another slider. Now I want to limit the thumb of the second slider to the range set with the range slider.